# Two UITableViews in one UIViewController with custom prototype cells gives errors

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift3

im learning swift and i am trying to build an app for logging workouts.

I'm using diefferent views and prototype cells and it works perfect.

But now on one view i have two tableviews, with each of them has the same kind of prototype cell, which is also a custom cell:

```
import UIKit

class muscleCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var lblDescription: UILabel!
    var id : Int64?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

It has just an ID and a label. I have used it in another tableview and it works perfect.

I have found here on stackoverflow how to use multiple UITableViews in one View and it showed me the data perfectly with the standard cell.

But as soon as i add the identifier in the storyboard, and make the outlet connections and use these identifiers in the code i get an error.

a quick info, i have tried this line:

```
self.lvMainMuscles.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "mainMuscleCell")
```

also like this (cause i found it somehwere that it might help):

```
self.lvMainMuscles.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

but did also not work.

```
import UIKit

class MachineController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtType: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var deleteToolbar: UIToolbar!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnDelete: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBOutlet weak var lvMainMuscles: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lvSupportingMuscles: UITableView!

    var machineId: Int64?
    var objMachine = Machine(connection: wpdb().db!)

    var objMuscle = Muscle(connection: wpdb().db!)
    var mainMuscleData : Array<Muscle.structMuscleList> = []
    var supportingMuscleData : Array<Muscle.structMuscleList> = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if (machineId != nil) {
            if (objMachine.loadById(Id: machineId!) == true) {
                self.title = objMachine.name
                txtName.text = objMachine.name
                txtType.text = String(objMachine.typeId)
            }
        } else {
            deleteToolbar.isHidden = true
        }

        lvMainMuscles.delegate = self
        lvMainMuscles.dataSource = self
        lvMainMuscles.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        self.lvMainMuscles.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "mainMuscleCell")

        lvSupportingMuscles.delegate = self
        lvSupportingMuscles.dataSource = self
        lvSupportingMuscles.allowsMultipleSelection = true

        self.lvSupportingMuscles.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "supportingMuscleCell")

        getData()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func btnSaveClick(_ sender: Any) {

        objMachine.name = txtName.text!
        objMachine.isSystem = false
        objMachine.typeId = Int64(txtType.text!)!

        let returnId = objMachine.save()
        print("edited/saved id: \(returnId)")

        let selectedrows = lvMainMuscles.indexPathsForSelectedRows

        if (selectedrows?.count)! > 0 {
            for row in selectedrows! {
                print(row.row)
            }
        }
        _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

    }

    @IBAction func btnDeleteClick(_ sender: Any) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: "Do you really want to delete the machine?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default, handler: { action in
            if self.objMachine.delete() == true {
                _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

            }
        })
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func getData() {
        mainMuscleData = objMuscle.getList()
        supportingMuscleData = objMuscle.getList()
        //  searchTextField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == self.lvMainMuscles {
            return mainMuscleData.count
        } else {
            return supportingMuscleData.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell:muscleCell!

        if tableView == self.lvMainMuscles {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mainMuscleCell") as! muscleCell
            cell.lblDescription.text = mainMuscleData[indexPath.row].description
        }

        if tableView == self.lvSupportingMuscles {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "supportingMuscleCell") as! muscleCell
            cell.lblDescription.text = supportingMuscleData[indexPath.row].description
        }
        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       // tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
        if tableView == lvMainMuscles {
            let cell = self.lvMainMuscles.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark;
        } else {
            let cell = self.lvSupportingMuscles.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark;
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if tableView == lvMainMuscles {
            let cell = self.lvMainMuscles.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none;
        } else {
            let cell = self.lvSupportingMuscles.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none;
        }
    }
```

the error I get is:

> Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x10a63c778) to
>   'WorkoutPartner.muscleCell' (0x107b422f0).
>   in this line:

```
cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "supportingMuscleCell") as! muscleCell
```

I don't understand why, since I am using the same cell in another view and it works.

i hope you have got an idea,

thank you very much

JYB

Comment: Have you created UITableViewCell via XIB or within the storyboard?

Comment: Why the Downvote? 
I did make the Class, then i put a prototypecell in the storyboard, then i changed the class of the cell to my customcell. after that i insert a label and connect it with the label in my customcell class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question and code what I understood is that the two tables have same design for the cells in same `UIView`.

In this case whenever a cell design is reused, we should make an `XIB` of your custom table cell, register that **NIB** with table and then deque in `cellForRow`

Here is a quick [Sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rc9kn3dr24z6xno/TwoTables.zip?dl=0) I made for you.

Here is the controller code part:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var firstTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondTable: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        firstTable.dataSource = self
        firstTable.delegate = self
        secondTable.dataSource = self
        secondTable.delegate = self

        //Registering Cell with tables
        self.firstTable.register(UINib(nibName: "MuscleTableCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MuscleTableCell")
        self.secondTable.register(UINib(nibName: "MuscleTableCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MuscleTableCell")

    }

}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == self.firstTable {
            return 5
        } else {
            return 2
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView == self.firstTable {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MuscleTableCell") as! MuscleTableCell
            cell.descriptionLabel.text = "Muscle Table Cell"
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MuscleTableCell") as! MuscleTableCell
            cell.descriptionLabel.text = "Supporting Table Cell"
            return cell
        }
    }
}
```

The `CustomCellClass`

```
import UIKit

class MuscleTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

The Custom Cell have its nib file too.[image]

And the **Output**:[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your help and your example project, i will try it! 
Interesting fact: i have deleted the  self.lvMainMuscles.register() and the  self.lvSupportingMuscles.register() rows and it seems to work now. i get back later for my update. thank you very much

Comment: ok this one did work if i dont "add" my cell in the storyboard, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You have registered UITableViewCell.self for the UITableView to use, therefore, it is returning that. Try registering your custom cell class instead.

Comment: tried that before did not work, but now i deleted the whole register class and it worked... i am a little confused now...

Answer (score 0):

OK if someone has the same problem:

I solved it by removing these two lines of code:

```
self.lvMainMuscles.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "mainMuscleCell")
```

and

```
self.lvSupportingMuscles.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "supportingMuscleCell")
```

I think my error was, that I registered the cell although I have a prototype cell in my storyboard.